# arr[Symbol.iterator] is not a function when using useState with context

Tags: reactjs, react-context, react-state

I want to use a react state within my Context. It looks like this:

```
export const App = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("test");
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <ViewContext.Provider value={{value, setValue}}>
          <Route path="/" render={(props) => <AdminLayout {...props} />} />
          <Route
            path="/Dashboard"
            render={(props) => <AdminLayout {...props} />}
          />
        </ViewContext.Provider>
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And all my exports are there. Then I call the  within my index like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <App></App>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

This does work if I use an context with e.g.: value="Test", but when I try to use it with a state, it does not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
export const App = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("test");
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <ViewContext.Provider value={value}> <----- you have to use like this
          <Route path="/" render={(props) => <AdminLayout {...props} />} />
          <Route
            path="/Dashboard"
            render={(props) => <AdminLayout {...props} />}
          />
        </ViewContext.Provider>
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: can you share codesandbox link of your code and your problem statement is very vague. So please specify clearly

Comment: I cannot share it, because you have to be logged in to certain servers to run the code. But there is not much more to it than this. The code runs perfectly without useState, but once I use it, it crashes...

Comment: check with single braces {value}..else try out like this:

        <ViewContext.Provider value={[value, setvalue]}>
         //your code here
        </ViewContext.Provider>

Comment: Yes. Brackets does work :-) However, I am not able to set the value from another component...

Comment: upvote  my code then pls :)
Another component means? not this one above you shared the snippet?

Comment: No. I do import the context inside another component, and use it likes this: const[value,setValue] = useContext(ViewContext).

And when I do: setValue("test") and try to print it, the old value is showing.

Comment: I did a mistake. Problem solved! Thanks for helping me.

Comment: great ! that's what i was thinking even .. becoz it should work!! If solved then upvote the post so that it will help others fastly(and remains on top)